# How to custom draw a cell in SourceGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using SourceGrid (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SourceGrid) in my WinForms app and I want to custom draw a cell.  I have found a way to do it, I just feel there must be a better, less hacky way. Here is what I do:

When creating a new cell:

```
Cell c = new Cell(Value);
var v = new SourceGrid.Cells.Views.Cell();
v.ElementText = new MyCustomCellElement(); // this will draw for me
c.View = v;
```

Later when filling the cells with data:

```
((Grid[row][col].View as SourceGrid.Cells.Views.Cell).ElementText as MyCustomCellElement).MyCustomData = MyCustomObj;
```

And the code that does the custom draw:

```
class MyCustomCellElement : DevAge.Drawing.VisualElements.TextGDI
{
    public MyObject MyCustomData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnDraw(GraphicsCache graphics, RectangleF area)
    {
        if (Value == null || Value.Length == 0)
            return;

        SolidBrush brush;
        if (Enabled)
            brush = graphics.BrushsCache.GetBrush(ForeColor);
        else
            brush = graphics.BrushsCache.GetBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.GrayText));

        // do your draw here, this is the default:
        graphics.Graphics.DrawString(Value, Font, brush, area, StringFormat);
    }
}
```

The double cast when putting data in the cell doesn't smell right - it is a hack. It works but I am sure there is a 'proper' way to do it.